# Navigation with NavDeepLinkBuilder creating fragment twice

Tags: android, kotlin

I've found the issue but i can't understand why it is happening.

In the MainActivity i choose the startDestination:

```
navController.graph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.navigation)
    .apply {
        runBlocking {
            startDestination =
                if (viewModel.userIsLoggedIn()) R.id.mainFragment
                else R.id.LoginFragment
        }
    }
```

Then when i send a notification i use this as the pendingtIntent

```
val pendintIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
        .setDestination(R.id.someFragment)
        .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
        .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
        .createTaskStackBuilder().getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

This works fine, when i clicked on the notification it navigates to the desired fragment, but it creates that fragment twice and i don't know why.

If i removed the startDestination chooser in the MainActivity it only creates one instace of the fragment.

I've also tried but didn't worked.

```
val pendingItent = 
        ...
        .setGraph(navController.graph)
        ...
```

Any ideas why is this happening and how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is late, but I faced the same issue and was able to figure out why this was happening.
In your MainActivity, you dynamically set your navigation graph and choose its start destination based on some condition, you probably do this in your onCreate method.
But when you navigate using the NavDeepLinkBuilder, it clears your current [Task](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) and recreates it. A task is a collection of activities, arranged in a stack, that the user interacts with.
From the documentation of NavDeepLinkBuilder:

> When this deep link is triggered:
>
> The task is cleared.
>
> The destination and all of its parents will be on the back stack.
>
> Calling NavController.navigateUp will navigate to the parent of the
> destination.

What this means is that using the NavDeepLinkBuilder to navigate to a deep link will kill your MainActivity and recreate it, so your code to initialize your nav graph and start destination will run, then the system will also recreate your nav graph, this causes 2 instances of your start destination to be created.

If you still want to Navigate using the NavDeepLikBuilder, you'll have to let the system create your nav graph for you using the XML configuration from your nav graph and navHostFragment.

Or you can leave your current setup of inflating your graph and setting the start destination yourself and handle notification clicks using pendingIntents and passing flags which you could then check for in your MainActivity and do the appropriate navigation.

Create your pending intent:

```
 val notificationIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("extra_key_1", your_extra)
        putExtra("extra_key_2", your_second_extra)
    }


    val notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        10,
        notificationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
```

Create your notification passing in the pending intent created above:

```
 val notification  =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Your_Notification_Channel")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                //rest of your notification config
                .build()
```

Then in your MainActivity onCreate and onNewIntent check for intent extras and perform your required navigation:

```
 val extra1 = intent.getStringExtra("extra_key_1")       
 if(extra1 != null){
    navHost.navcontroller.navigate(your_fragment_uri)
 }
```

You can also set the launch mode of your MainActivity in your manifest to singleInstance so that the same instance of the Activity always gets the intent.